# Creating an "at" job from command line for a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, unix, at-job

From the command line, I want to create an at job to run a mysql query.  As you can imagine searching on google or here stackoverflow for "at" is difficult.

This works fine and the query runs like it ought to:

```
mysql -e 'MY QUERY;'
```

but if I do this:

```
at 17:30 mysql -e 'MY QUERY;'
```

At 5:30 I get a mail that tells me "UPDATE: command not found" and the query doesn't run.  I set up a .my.cnf file already.  Is there something else I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a shell escape issue.  The shell is likely eating the quotes.  Try double quoting like so:

```
at 17:30 mysql -e "\"MY QUERY;\""
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have a related question I'll ask next.